# Delete data using ViewScoped

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, view-scope

i'm using ViewScoped in my controller but i need to do something wired..
i want to mantain the data when using that view but if i leave that view, and then return i dont want the data there!

```
@Component("sponsorController")
@ViewScoped
public class SponsorController implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Autowired
      private SponsorClientFacade ejbFacade;
```

should i switch scope?or this is the right one?

Comment: but if i use that scope the data will remain there.. but i dont want that

Comment: What do you mean by "leave that view"? Are you navigating to a different view then?

Comment: imagine this, i have one menu that can go to 2 pages , each has one table.. if i go to page A the controller populate the table.. if i back to menu and select page A again i want the table to be empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't do want i want with this way..
My solution was specify a onclick method in the hyperlynk and that method clear all views..
Thanks for the help